# How to extract content from a text file using sed command when line ranges are given?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

```
#!/bin/bash

export ORACLE_SID=orcl
export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
export LOG_DIR=$ORACLE_BASE/diag/rdbms/$ORACLE_SID/$ORACLE_SID/trace

LINE_COUNT_OLD=0

while true
do  
    LINE_COUNT=`wc -l $LOG_DIR/alert_orcl.log | awk '{print $1}'`
    DIFF=`expr $LINE_COUNT - $LINE_COUNT_OLD`
    if [ $DIFF -ne 0 ] && [ $LINE_COUNT_OLD -ne 0 ]
    then
        COUNT=0
        COUNT=`tail -$DIFF $LOG_DIR/alert_orcl.log|grep 'ORA-'|wc -l`
        if [ $COUNT -ne 0 ]
        then
            sed -n '$LINE_COUNT_OLD, $LINE_COUNT' $LOG_DIR/alert_orcl.log > $LOG_DIR/alert_orcl_tmp.log
            cat $LOG_DIR/alert_orcl_tmp.log >> $LOG_DIR/alert_orcl_email.log
        fi
    fi
    sleep 10
    LINE_COUNT_OLD=$LINE_COUNT
    rm -f $LOG_DIR/alert_orcl_tmp.log 
done
```

In the above bash script getting below error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 3: extra characters after command
```

So I have poblem with `sed -n` command. But replacing vairables with numbers like below line, this command is working fine

```
sed -n '6512, 6671 p' $LOG_DIR/alert_orcl.log
```

Need help to pass the variable in `sed -n` command

Comment: Use *double-quotes* `sed -n "$LINE_COUNT_OLD, $LINE_COUNT"...` (single quoting prevents variable expansion) Also, don't use antiquated `expr $LINE_COUNT - $LINE_COUNT_OLD` just use `DIFF=$((LINE_COUNT - LINE_COUNT_OLD))` Also, do not use `ALLCAPS` variable names, those are typically reserved for use by the shell `:)` You also need to *double-quote* all variables, especially in `[...]` to prevent *word-splitting* from taking place.

Comment: Thanks David for your valuable suggestions. It is working now.

Comment: Good glad it helped. You can wait and see if you get other answers, but make sure you select one as answering your question by selecting the green check next the number at the top-left of the answer. That way this question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 2):

Your primary problem with your `sed` command occurs because you have *single-quoted* the variables in:

```
sed -n '$LINE_COUNT_OLD, $LINE_COUNT' ...
```

When you *single-quote* variables, you prevent *variable expansion* by the shell, so `sed` literally sees:

```
sed -n '$LINE_COUNT_OLD, $LINE_COUNT' ...
```

where it attempts to resolve the literal range `$LINE_COUNT_OLD, $LINE_COUNT` from the characters `'$' 'L' 'I' 'N' 'E' '_' 'C' 'O' 'U' 'N' 'T' '_' 'O' 'L' 'D', ...`

To correct the problem, *double quote* you variables:

```
sed -n "$LINE_COUNT_OLD, $LINE_COUNT" ...
```

Next you have a number of little things you should update. First, avoid the use of `expr $LINE_COUNT - $LINE_COUNT_OLD` that is an antiquated (and slow) way of doing arithmetic. Instead use the arithmetic operators `$((LINE_COUNT - LINE_COUNT_OLD))`  (**note:** `$` dereference of the variables within `$((..))` is not required)

Next, unless you know the exact reason not to quote, you should *double-quote* all variables in bash to prevent *word-splitting*. Especially within `[...]`. Otherwhise if there is any whitespace in your variable, you will be passing an incorrect number of arguments to `test`. Likewise, it is also a good idea to quote the non-variables with `[...]` such as `-ne '0'` (*single-quotes* are fine here).

Lastly, avoid the use of `ALLCAPS` variable names. Those are typically reserved for use by the shell.

Answer (score 1):

Use double-quoted string to pass the required parameters, so it can be evaluated by shell.

```
sed -n "$varA, $varB" $LOG_DIR/alert_orcl.log
```